# Problem counting values, not returning anything

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula but for some reason is not returning anything, can someone help me? Thanks

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&Ranges!A2,B:B,"<="&Ranges!B2+0.999988,C:C,">=Ranges!$D$2",C:C,"<=Ranges!$E$2")
```

Comment: The last part is wrong - it should be `C:C,">="&Ranges!$D$2,C:C,"<="&Ranges!$E$2` not `C:C,">=Ranges!$D$2",C:C,"<=Ranges!$E$2"`

Comment: @Rory Thank you. If you submit this as an answer I can select it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the criteria wrong in the last part - they should use similar syntax to the first two - in other words:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&Ranges!A2,B:B,"<="&Ranges!B2+0.999988,C:C,">="&Ranges!$D$2,C:C,"<="&Ranges!$E$2)
```